# Is Leslie Lamport's pf2.sty still available?

Tags: packages

I want to use Leslie Lamport's pf2.sty for laying out mathematical proofs, but the link on [Lamport's page](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/latex.html) appears to be broken. Is there any way I can get the file?

Comment: on lamport's web page, he says that what's shown in this `.gif` file will reach him.  http://www.lamport.org/cowspots3.gif  all the links on that page that point to `.sty` files are broken, but the documentation remains accessible; a useless situation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Looks like Microsoft did some nonsense redirecting http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/ to http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/index.html which may be the reason for the link breakage. Hopefully they fix it soon.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR -- they probably won't fix it unless someone tells them to though.

Comment: This appears to be fixed now: the link from [Lamport's "Useful LaTeX packages" page](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/latex.html) to [pf2.sty](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/pf2.sty) works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the heading saying **pf.sty** I think that this is pf2 from google's cache

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GmTvkzjvNK0J:research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/latex/pf2.sty

Comment: From the amendment date, that looks right. Thanks.